# Example of epimorphisms such that the product is not an epimorphism in the category of sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

I've heard that in the category of sheaves over a topological space $X$, products of epimorphisms are not epimorphisms. I think that it's equivalent to saying that $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ does not satisfy AB4. However I could not find an example.

Comment: Could you please state AB4?

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz  here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/additive+and+abelian+categories it's pretty standard since it's from Tohoku's paper

Comment: Old question, but I thought I'd point out that this property (product of epimorphisms is an epimorphism) is actually axiom AB4*, and AB4 is its dual (coproduct of monomorphisms is a monomorphism).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The product of finitely many epimorphisms is an epimorphism; the problem is infinite products. Let $X$ be a topological space with lots of open subsets, e.g. $[0, 1]$. Choose a sequence of open covers $\mathfrak{U}_0, \mathfrak{U}_1, \mathfrak{U}_2, \ldots$ of $X$ with the following properties:

- Each $\mathfrak{U}_{n+1}$ refines $\mathfrak{U}_n$.
- If $U$ is an open subset of $X$ such that $U$ is contained in some member of $\mathfrak{U}_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then $U = \emptyset$.

For example, if $X = [0, 1]$, we could take $\mathfrak{U}_n$ to be the collection of open balls of radius $2^{-n}$ centred on points in $2^{-n} \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, let $\mathscr{F}_n$ be the abelian sheaf freely generated by $\mathfrak{U}_n$. (This is the sheaf associated with the presheaf $U \mapsto \bigoplus_{U' \in \mathfrak{U}_n, U \subseteq U'} \mathbb{Z}$.) It is not hard to see that, for any given open $U \subseteq X$, we have $\Gamma (U, \mathscr{F}_n) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Nonetheless, there is an epimorphism $\mathscr{F}_n \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by sending each generator to $1$. However, consider $\prod_{n \ge 0} \mathscr{F}_n \to \prod_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{Z}$. We have $\Gamma (U, \prod_{n \ge 0} \mathscr{F}_n) \cong \prod_{n \ge 0} \Gamma (U, \mathscr{F}_n)$ for all $U$, so $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is not even locally in the image. Thus  $\prod_{n \ge 0} \mathscr{F}_n \to \prod_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{Z}$ is not an epimorphism.

That said, there are topological spaces where products of epimorphisms are still epimorphisms: for instance, the spectrum of a local Dedekind domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what exactly do you mean by "lots of open sets"? You mean infinite countable different neighborhoods? Furthermore, have you made it by your own or it's from a kind of more general technique?

Comment: I mean enough to make the argument work. This construction is more or less obvious once you believe that products of epimorphisms are not always epimorphisms.

Comment: For any $U$, we have $U = \bigcup_{U' \in \mathfrak{U}_n} U' \cap U$, and the value of the presheaf on each of those intersections is $\mathbb{Z}$ in your specific example. In particular, the sheafification which you call $\mathscr{F}_n$ is going to have $\mathbb{Z}$ as its global sections, and doesn't have the property $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F}_n) = 0$ that you claim. Maybe this example will work if you instead stick to presheaves on the frame of opens of $X$?

Comment: On second thought, we need to consider also the values at $U'' \cap U' \cap U$ in order to compute the sheafification, and this is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ whenever the intersection is non-empty in your example, so $\mathscr{F}_n$ is going to be even bigger than I thought!

Comment: That is not the presheaf I described. The restriction maps are not set up to allow you to amalgamate sections from different elements of the cover.

Comment: There are no amalgamations in the presheaf, but on the contrary you cannot *prevent* there from being amalgamations in the sheafification. When n=0, for example, you have opens $U_0 = [0,1)$ and $U_1 = (0,1]$, and the presheaf has $F(U) = \emptyset$ if $\{0,1\} \subseteq U$, $\mathbb{Z}$ if  exactly one of $0,1$ is in $U$ and $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ otherwise. Taking $U_0,U_1$ as an open cover of the interval, for each $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ we have a matching family which is $a$ on $U_0$, $b$ on $U_1$ and $(a,b)$ on their intersection

Comment: , since the restriction maps must preserve the generators. So $\mathscr{F}(X) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: That's not a matching family.

Comment: Ah, I see, $b \mapsto (0,b)$ rather than $(a,b)$. Thanks...