# How to prove that the analogue of this theorem is valid for $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modules

How to prove that the analogue of this theorem is valid for $\mathbb{R}$-modules?
because the book did not prove it for groups so I have no idea how to prove it.
Could anyone help me please?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
My professor told me that I can solve it like this question(I know how to solve this question), but it also the details is not so clear for me, could anyone give me a more detailed hint please?
[image]

Comment: What is the notation $\prod_{i\in I}^w G_i$ means? Specifically $w$?

Comment: I will add a definition for it in my question @Krish

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: My professor solved it for me my using category theory and drawing diagrams but I did not understand this solution. Also she mentioned for me that I can do it like question 4 which I uploaded its picture above (I know how to solve this question) but I also not understanding exactly what I can do ......... so if you gave me a more detailed hint I will be very thankful for you :) thank! @Guest

Comment: Sorry I mean like question 2 @Guest

Comment: Usually we use the bold $\mathbb{R}$ to represent the field of real numbers, so it is better to replace it by $R$ in your title.

Comment: Ok sorry I will correct it @Phil.Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave out the part with the weak products.

You can define $f$ by universal property of the product if you require 
 $$ \pi_i \circ f =  f_i \circ \pi_i .$$ 
Where $\pi_i$ is the projection to the $i$th componten of the product.

Now if you assume that $fg=fh$, then you have
$$  f_i \circ \pi_i \circ g =f_i \circ \pi_i \circ h.$$

If all $f_i$ are mono then $\pi_i \circ g =\pi_i \circ h$ by univeral property of the product this gives $g=h$, hence $f$ is mono.

Conversely if $f$ is mono and $g_i,h_i \colon D \to G_i$, then if $f_ig_i=f_ih_i$ for all $i$ $fg=fh$, hence $g=h$ and $g_i= h_i$ for all $i$. Thus we know all $f_i$ must be mono. (I implicitly used that there is a map from $D$ to $G_i$ for all $i$)

Now the epi part: same as before we can show if $f$ is epi then all $f_i$ are epi too.

So far you didn't really need anything special about groups and modules. But next [doesn't hold in every category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674482/example-of-epimorphisms-such-that-the-product-is-not-an-epimorphism-in-the-categ). You could show that epis in modules/groups are surjective. Then show the corresponding result for sets and since the forgetful functor reflects epimorphisms you get the result. I.e. if $f_i$ are epimorphisms, show that they are surjective, then show that their product $f$ is surjective and show that surjective morphisms in modules/groups are epis.

You also can show that in groups and modules the monos are the injective maps and the epis are the surjective maps. Since every module is a group the result then also holds for groups.

Comment: Could you provide a detailed source for me for defining the universal property of $f$ as Hungerford algebra defined it in a different way.

Comment: Why you leave out the part with the weak products?

Comment: @Idonotknow the universal property says something like a map into a product is uniquely defined if it is given on any factor of the product. Now you define it on the $i$th factor on $H$ to be $f_i$ on the $i$th component on $G$. That’s the only thing you can do. But if you want to work in the categorical setting you need to use the universal properties as much as you can.

Comment: @Idonotknow I didn’t had an idea how to do it in a way I like. I will at something about weak products later

Comment: it is better for me if you used commutative diagrams.