# Direct sum of injections is injection, categorically

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, direct-sum, universal-property

Given $R$-module maps $\{f_i \colon M_i \to N_i\}_{i \in I}$, the universal properties of the direct sums $\oplus M_i$ and $\oplus N_i$ give a unique map $\oplus f_i \colon \oplus M_i \to \oplus N_i$ such that $M_j \xrightarrow{f_j} N_j \to \oplus N_i$ agrees with $M_j \to \oplus M_j \xrightarrow{\oplus f_j} \oplus N_i$ for each $j \in I$. (The unlabeled maps are the inclusions.)

If we use the explicit constructions of $\oplus M_i$ and $\oplus N_i$ as sets of tuples $\{(m_i)_{i \in I} \mid m_i \in M_i\}$ and $\{(n_i)_{i \in I} \mid n_i \in N_i\}$, then the map $\oplus f_i$ is given explicitly by $(m_i) \mapsto (f(m_i))$. Now it's easy to see that if $f_i$ is an injection for all $i$, then $\oplus f_i$ is, too.

However, I was wondering if there's a way to reason about injectivity of $\oplus f_i$ directly from the universal properties, without using any particular construction for the direct sum.

Comment: Proceeding using only the universal property of direct sum and the universal property for kernels gets you a relation $ker(\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} f_i)\circ h = \bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} (ker(f_i))$. But, the furthest I could get here was using injectivity of $f_i$ and the abelian category property to show $h$ was the zero map. Basically, this was in effort to show the kernel of the direct sum map was trivial. But you get a free condition in the end. Using biproducts (in the finite case) didn’t help, nor did taking cokernels. I don’t think it is provable via universal properties alone..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C$ is a category with infinite coproducts, taking $I$-indexed coproducts is a functor $\bigoplus : C^I \to C$ which is left adjoint to the diagonal functor $\Delta : C \to C^I$, and hence which preserves colimits. This implies that it preserves *epimorphisms*, since those are the morphisms with trivial [cokernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel+pair) (in an abelian category substitute "cokernel"). However, there's no abstract nonsense reason it should preserve monomorphisms; those are the morphisms with trivial kernel pair (again, in an abelian category substitute "kernel"), so this would be a limit-commuting-with-colimit type scenario, which usually requires special hypotheses.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715022/232) you can find a counterexample by Zhen Lin in the abelian category $\text{Sh}([0, 1])^{op}$, the opposite of the category of sheaves of abelian groups on the interval.